# http::request to internal link return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

I'm trying to call internal action using http::request, but it always giving nil in it's response.body.

Here is the code in the view file,

```
<%= @res.body.html_safe %>
```

Here is the code in controller

```
def index2
    require "net/http"
    require "uri"

    url = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/")

    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.request_uri)
    req.set_form_data({'email'=>'torturer21.21@gmail.com', 'pass'=>'zeas2345'})
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

    @res = http.request(req)
end
```

and the result is

> ## NoMethodError in Main#index2

```
Showing D:/WORK/ERP_BALIYONI/app/views/main/index2.html.erb where line #5 raised:
undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass

2:   
3: %>
4: 
5: <%= @res.body.html_safe %>
```

I'm quite confused because when I change the url into

```
url = URI.parse("http://localhost3000.org/")
```

it works.
Can you help me find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your response get `nil`

`@res = http.request(req)` here `@res` is nil so when you try `@res.body` it is throwing `undefined method body for nil:NilClass`

you can ty

in index.html.erb:

`<%= @res.try(:body).try(:html_safe) %>`

Comment: I find this did not help.

Comment: What i really want to know is why my code returning nil.

Comment: as you already told your uri was wrong that 's why response was  nil

Comment: Thats make sense, but isn't it also mean that i could not access my internal server link?

Comment: did your server running ? did localhost:300 in browser show data

Comment: It did, so i find this much confusing. FYI, i'm calling this function inside localhost:3000/main/index2/new.

Comment: The `localhost3000.org` is an external link, and it's working. The one i was trying to access is `http://localhost:3000/`